# Power Bi DAX error for function Date has the wrong data type or the result is too large

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization

I have a measure which currently calculates the numbers of the one month to the last weeks worth of data. This doesn't work when changing the numbers to 30 and 60 instead of 7 and 35 in DAX

```
Stars_Prior = 
VAR StartDate = SELECTEDVALUE('Review Dates'[date],max('Dates'[date]))
VAR CurrentDate = DATE(YEAR(StartDate),MONTH(StartDate),DAY(StartDate)-30)
VAR PriorDate =DATE(YEAR(StartDate),MONTH(StartDate),DAY(StartDate)-60)
RETURN
CALCULATE(

    SUM('data'[rate]),

    FILTER(

        'data',

        'data'[Date] > PriorDate && 'data'[Date] <= CurrentDate

    )

)


Stars_Current = 

VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE('Review Dates'[date],max('Review Dates'[date]))
VAR PriorDate =DATE(YEAR(CurrentDate),MONTH(CurrentDate),DAY(CurrentDate)-30)

RETURN

CALCULATE(

    SUM('data'[rate]),

    FILTER(
        'data',
        'data'[Date] > PriorDate && 'data'[Date] <= CurrentDate
    )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh1KK.png)

Comment: Not tested but from **help** for DAX `DATE` function: *Negative integers are not supported.*  Suggest you look at `DATEADD` function

Comment: did you mean VAR CurrentDate =DATEADD(day(Startdate),-30,DAY)? doesn't work the error parameter is incorrect

Comment: Also tried without dat().No luck

Comment: I suggest you read SO HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also, it might help to read MS HELP for the DAX `DATEADD` function.  Then **edit your question** to provide sufficient information so someone can reproduce your problem.